# How do you submit a form to an app engine python application without refreshing the sending page?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, forms, submit, datastore

As a newbie to app engine and python I can follow the examples given by Google and have created a python application with a template HTML page where I can enter data, submit it to the datastore and by reading back the data, just sent, recreate the sending page so I can continue adding data and store again.  However what I would like to do is submit the data, have it stored in the datastore without the sending page being refreshed. It seems like a waste of traffic to have all the data sent back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX. If you want a specific resource concerning AppEngine -

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html (uses Python) is very good.

Here is a good link to understand [Communication with Server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls) on Google App Engine

Comment: Thanks for this. Had hoped there was a simpler way built into the AppEngine but will now persevere with AJAX

Comment: It is not very difficult once you get the hold of it. In the rpc article I have suggested, the request is made using JavaScript. That may look scary if you are new. Using jQuery or some other JavaScript library can hugely simplify that part.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want to look into AJAX. The simplest way to do this is probably to use the ajax functions in one of the popular Javascript libraries, like jQuery.

Comment: +1 There are tons of examples on how to do this, here is a pretty straight forward one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/  Just replace the backend code with whatever you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Pyjamas pyjs.org

It's a Python Compiler for web browsers. Write your client side in Python and Pyjamas will compile it into JavaScript.